# onChange monitoring user input into TextField component from Office-UI-Fabric on every render and displaying incorrect output

Tags: react-hooks, office-ui-fabric, react-tsx

I am trying to implement a UI where i take user input through the TextField component from Office-ui-fabric. I use onChange to monitor value. However, as i type in user input say the number '100' i can see the function rendered each time which i believe is a feature of onChange but after completing typing in my input i see only '10' in the console window.

I tried changing onChange to Blur as suggested in an old stackoverflow post but when i do that i don't see any console messages.

```
const [msg, setMsg] = React.useState("");
React.useEffect(()=>{
   vscode.postMessage(
     {
       command: 'setMsg',
       text: msg
     }
   );
},[msg])

return (
<div>
 <Stack>
   <Stack.Item grow>
   <Label style={{ color: 'white' }}>Enter number </Label>
   <TextField placeholder="Enter number of images" value={msg} onChange={event => { setMsg((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value); console.log(msg);test() }} /> 
   </Stack.Item>
   </Stack>
</div>
);
```

I expect if i enter the number '100' i should see '100' in the console log. Currently i see'10'. Is this the right way to implement this functionality? New to react and office -ui-fabric and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi novice_coder, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` in `React` is `async` and takes some time to execute / update state.

When you do this,

```
onChange={event => { 
   setMsg((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value); 
   console.log(msg);
   test() 
}}
```

After `setState` you are trying to access the state which will in result gives you the previous state only.

To see actual effect, remove this `console.log` from `onChange` and make use of `useEffect` hook. As you already have `useEffect` which will execute on `msg` change, you just need to add `console.log(msg)` line in it.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(msg); // Now you will get updated value every time.
        vscode.postMessage(
            {
                command: 'setMsg',
                text: msg
            }
        );
},[msg])
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried your suggestion and it works. The only problem being i input the value in the TextField say 1000 but i don't see the console log immediately. I give user input to another TextField is when i can see the value of msg = 1000 in the console. Is this a side effect of my implementation? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Here dependency array comes into picture, as you provided dependency array to `useEffect` it will only run when that dependency gets changed. For any other input change it will not execute this `useEffect`. If you want to show state value on every render you can simply use `useEffect` without any dependency like `useEffect(() =>{console.log(msg)})`.Now this will execute on any input change.

Comment: You can add any number of `useEffect`.

Comment: @novice_coder, can you also provide steps for this *The only problem being i input the value in the TextField say 1000 but i don't see the console log immediately.  I give user input to another TextField is when i can see the value of msg = 1000 in the console.*

Comment: Thank you you for your help but i figured out the issue. I was erroneously  monitoring the function setMsg instead of msg in useEffect.